# An alternative term for "Sponsoring Organization" or "Produced By..."

Tags: synonyms

I'm reworking my personal/professional website, and listing projects (mostly web development.) Several of them were entirely done by myself, but many are while being employed by another entity to do so. I'd like to list those projects, since they are extremely relevant, along with what my actual contribution was, but I'm having trouble coming across a word that I would prefer to use under the listing.

- "Sponsoring Organization: Company"?
- "Created By: Company"?
- "Produced By: Company"?

For whatever reason, none of those really sit right with me, and I was wondering if someone had a better idea.

Comment: Sponsor or Client.

Comment: "Created with:" or "Created for:" ?

Comment: @UnsettlingTrend: I tried to change "_employed buy_" to "_employed by_" but the system wouldn't accept it because the correction was too short (?). Mind to do it yourself?

Comment: @Hank: fine, thanks. How did you manage to do it?

Comment: @Chiron At 2k reputation, you get the ability to edit without gathering approval. You also don't have a minimum change limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*Supported by:*" might be vague enough and still say that you did it while someone else was paying the bills.

Comment: I'm going to go with this one. I feel like it's the best compromise for myself. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, UnsettlingTrend. I'm glad I did something useful.

Answer (score 2):

Plain *For:* would give you plenty of scope to include anything you did for somebody else, without requiring you to indicate the precise nature of the relationship, which should be irrelevant.

Comment: I'm okay with stating the relationship though. It may take away from myself, I guess, but I really don't want to seem like I'm taking more credit than I deserve.